# How to create a responsive layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

i'm trying to create a login layout.

Preview phone 5.0" looks good:
https://imgur.com/oAukTkZ

If i run in device 6.0" look good. But, device 5.0" i see is very big
https://imgur.com/muMon2U

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/lightBlue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView1" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewWelcome" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWelcome"
        style="@style/tv24spffffff_googlesansmedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/selamat_datang"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textViewWelcomeDesc"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textViewWelcomeDesc" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWelcomeDesc"
        style="@style/tv14spffffff_robotomedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="@string/silahkan_login_untuk_masuk_ke_akun_anda"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txtForgotPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmailOrNoTelp"
                style="@style/AppTextFields"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:hint="@string/email_no_telp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmailOrNoTelp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
                style="@style/AppTextFields"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="29.61dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayoutEmailOrNoTelp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                style="@style/AppButtonBlue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48.7dp"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="@string/log_in"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayoutPassword" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForgotPassword"
        style="@style/tv13spffffff_googlesansmedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/lupa_password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one responsive layout can use:

- `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.x"`
- `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.y"`
- [Guideline](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html)

**Example layout:**

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                android:text="button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My idea is that you can create different layouts for different screen sizes. As it is described here at Android Developers: [Create alternative layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts).
To do it you should place your different layout files in different 'layout' directories. E.g. as in the docs: `res/layout/` as a 'default' directory and `res/layout-w600dp/` for layouts that are prepared to be used on screens with a width of 600dp or wider.

Comment: *create different layouts for different screen sizes* , sure you can do it but you can also use ConstraintLayout as I did in my answer, I think it's nicer to have single layout that is also responsive

Comment: Of course, it's also a good idea to consider. I haven't concluded percentage height and width layout parameters. But, I am not sure that it'd be always a nice thing. Sure, it's faster to implement – it's a very good advantage.

You should consider if you want scalable layouts or a static width on different screen sizes. It's a design matter. Scalable views could look bad with e.g. some font sizes.